# jQuery calling the function twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

We have this `jQuery` code that handles `tap` and `click`. We need to do this since old `ios` version does not support click only.

The problem is with latest `ios`, the function is being execute twice. Once from the click event and one for the tap event.

```js
$(".test").on("click tap", function(){
  console.log("yey!");
})
```

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"> CLICK HERE </div>
```

**Question:** How to prevent the lastest IOS from calling the function twice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on requirements:  `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` will stop the second event firing - it could also stop *other* events firing, so may not be suitable in all cases

Answer (score 0):

Use a more reliable event and test it

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints) { // it can be touched
    $(".test").on("touchend", handleInteraction);
} else { // it can be clicked
    $(".test").on("click", handleInteraction);
}
```